# Play Framework 2.4.1: How to migrate custom plugins

Tags: scala, playframework

As of Play 2.4 the `Plugin` class is deprecated and one should use the `Module` class instead.

I've understood file `play.plugins` is no longer necessary and custom modules should be registered in `application.conf` as documented [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.inject.Module).

But how do I migrate my old plugins? The `Module` class doesn't contain methods `onStart` and `onStop`... Is there an example somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This pull request has the full Redis plugin migration from 2.3 to 2.4.  They use the constructor for the `onStart` and `ApplicationLifecycle` for the `onStop` in `SedisPoolProvider`.

https://github.com/typesafehub/play-plugins/pull/148/files

[Documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaDependencyInjection#Play-libraries) explains that the goal is to provide bindings in a DI framework *agnostic* way.  This is the reason I believe there is no trait with `onStart` and `onStop` to implement. The agnostic way is to use constructor and/or by injecting a lifecycle module like `ApplicationLifecycle`.